# passing value from one jsp file to another jsp file

Tags: javascript, jsp, jakarta-ee

Suppose i'm having 2 jsp pages, page1 and page2.
Now i'm including page1 in page2.
I want to access some value from page1 and i want to access it within jsp scriplet tag, how can i get it without using cookie or session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access variables declared in a scriptlet in page1 from page2. This is one of the [disadvantages of scriptlets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files). Check out the answer by BalusC.

If you are using JSTL, you can do something like this in page1:

```
  <c:set var = "salary" scope = "session" value = "666"/>
```

or with request scope:

```
  <c:set var = "salary" scope = "request" value = "666"/>
```

And in page2:

```
<c:out value = "${salary}"/>
```

But really, you should be setting variables in your servlets which you can then access anywhere in the JSPs.. The use of scriptlets is highly discouraged.

Comment: Using JSP bean is better option then?

Comment: If you want to, but generally you should use scriptlets as little as possible, or avoid it completely if you can.